# How to express a fixed root of an equation in terms of a fixed root of another equation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, intuition

I'll ask this question by giving a concrete example, which in my opinion is easier to understand:

Premise: it is assumed that it is possible to do this because the two equations are connected related

> ### Easy example
>
> By hypothesis we know that the plastic constant $\rho$ solve this equation: $x^3-x-1=0$
> And the following equation is given:
> $27x^{3}+9x^{2}-3x+7=0$
> **We need to express the real root of this equation in terms of the root of the first**:
> The real solution to this equation is $x=-\dfrac{2}{3\rho}-\dfrac{1}{3}=-\dfrac{2}{3}\rho^{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}$
> This case is easy because you just need to manipulate the $x$ with sum and product operations.

But if for example I have an equation like this:

$$91125 x^6−425250 x^5+888975 x^4−607500 x^3+53955 x^2−690 x+3481=0$$

The **real** solutions are $x_1\approx 0.2565$ and $x_2\approx 0.9836$

I know that both are expressible in terms of $\rho$, but I don't know how to calculate it.

The only consideration I was able to make was consider $3\sqrt{5}x=t$ and simplify the equation to

$$t^{6}-14\sqrt{5}t^{5}+439t^{4}-900\sqrt{5}t^{3}+1199t^{2}-46\sqrt{5}t+3481=0$$

> Probably this equation can be divided into a product of this type:
> $$\left(t^3+(a_2+b_2)t^2+(a_1+b_1)t+(a_0+b_0)\right)\left(t^3+(a_2-b_2)t^2+(a_1-b_1)t+(a_0-b_0)\right)=0$$
> But it seems like a very long process to me, taking into account that I would also have to do this with higher degree polynomials.

Are there any faster methods that only require you to manipulate the "secondary" polynomial with the "primary" polynomial?

### Update

The polynomial is the product of

$$p_1(x)=135\sqrt{5}x^{3}-45(7\sqrt{5}\color{red}{+}10)x^{2}+3(147\sqrt{5}\color{red}{+}340)x-101\sqrt{5}\color{red}{-}218$$
and
$$p_2(x)=135\sqrt{5}x^{3}-45(7\sqrt{5}\color{red}{-}10)x^{2}+3(147\sqrt{5}\color{red}{-}340)x-101\sqrt{5}\color{red}{+}218$$

$x_1$ solves $p_1(x)$ and $x_2$ solve $p_2(x)$

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to tell us _how_ you know the roots of the sextic can be written in terms of $\rho$? That ought to be a clue as to how to find the actual expressions. Where does this problem come from? The title to your question is much too general.

Comment: @EthanBolker The equations refer to values ​​of the same solid ($U46$), which has $\rho$ as its characteristic constant, this means that all the values ​​of $U46$ can be expressed as a function of $\rho$. For example, for the icosahedron and the dodecahedron the characteristic constant is $\phi$, in fact some of their geometric properties (volume and angles) can expressed as a function of $\phi$. Then there are other solids that have more complicated characteristic constants, but I didn't want to create a problem with a 16th degree equation and I put this example which was one of the easiest.

Comment: @EthanBolker Don't look on Wikipedia because the values ​​that are reported there are wrong. (Not only those, for many other uniform solids it gives practically random numbers that I have no idea where it got from)

Comment: This is really a question about the relations among various constants describing attributes of a polyhedron.  The geometry must come into play. It might be helpful to look at the symmetry groups involved, maybe their representations? (Not a serious hint, just a first observation.) In any case if you want help you should completely rewrite the question to ask about what you really need to know, not some vague abstract generalization about roots of polynomials. Choose a few good tags. (No need to respond with further clarifying comments.)

Comment: is your question really about any polynomial of $x^6$ order, or this specific polynomial when $\rho$ is known?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou any polynomial of $n$-order. I might say something wrong, but by searching online I think the knowledge of field extensions or Galois groups is needed.

Comment: @EthanBolker You are right. In a few hours I'll ask a question again that also includes this information.

Comment: @EthanBolker I made it

Comment: You should probably delete this question. If not, at least link to it from the other question, and link that one here.

Comment: @EthanBolker I would like to delete it but it tells me "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center"

Comment: That's reasonable policy. Edit both questions to link to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the same idea as with the plastic constant which is also the sum of two real roots.

\begin{align}
 r_1 = & \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}\right)^{1/3} \qquad
 r_2 =  \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}\right)^{1/3} \\
 \rho =& \;r_1 +r_2 = \frac{(9-\sqrt{69})^{1/3}+(9+\sqrt{69})^{1/3}}{2^{1/3} 3^{2/3}} = 1.324717957..
\end{align}

Notice that the quadratic polynomial combining $r_1,r_2$ has simpler roots :
$$ x^2-\frac{1}{9} = (x- r_1 r_2) (x+r_1 r_2) = \left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

For the first polynomial $27x^{3}+9x^{2}-3x+7=0$ with only one real root you solved the relationsship without adding a new constant.

If for the second polynomial $$91125 x^6−425250 x^5+888975 x^4−607500 x^3+53955 x^2−690 x+3481=0$$
one uses the same idea as with the plastic constant one obtains a quadratic polynomial with roots which are of course more complicated but they also have $\sqrt{69}$ like the plastic constant as you can see:

$$x^2-\frac{1}{15^4}\left(-35 + \frac{\left(2^5\cdot 15^3\cdot 37 - 2^5\cdot 3\cdot 5^4\cdot 7 \sqrt{69}\right)^{1/3}}{3} + 
    10 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2/3} \left(3^2\cdot 7 + 35 \sqrt{69}\right)^{1/3}\right)^2 $$